# Message: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In Codeigniter I am creating some helpers to check user in certain group/s by allowing passing group name as a string or an array for multiple groups. Now seems things are working fine if I don't pass userid for `$id` argument. When I set the `$id` to some userid like `2` it is giving an error below

```
Message: Cannot use a scalar value as an array
```

Here is my all helper functions and than usage.

**Getting user's groups**

```
if ( !function_exists('get_user_group') )
{
    function get_user_group($id = FALSE)
    {
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // getting user groups by id or logged in
    $object = $CI->ion_auth->get_users_groups($id)->result();

    foreach($object as $group):
        $id[] = $group->id;
        $groups[] = $group->name;
    endforeach;
    $groups = array_combine($id, $groups);

    return $groups;

    }
}
```

**Check if User in the group/s**

```
if ( !function_exists('in_group') )
{
    function in_group($groups, $id = FALSE)
    {
    if(is_array($groups)){

        foreach($groups as $group){
        //print_r($group);
        if(in_array($group, get_user_group($id))){
            return TRUE;
        }
        }

    } elseif(is_string($group)) {
        if(in_array($group, get_user_group($id))){
        return TRUE;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
if(in_group(array('hr'), 2)){
    echo '<h1>IS IN THIS GROUP</h1>';
} else {
    echo '<h1>IS NOT IN THIS GROUP</h1>';
}
```

Comment: In `get_user_group()`, declare the $id array before use. But use different name like $ids. Because you already assigned FALSE to $id.

Comment: @kumar_v thanks for your feedback but can you please explain with some sort of example? I am unable to understand your comment clearly. Thanks..

Comment: Ah! got it works... Thanks a lot. I may post solution in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @kumar_v comment I have modified `get_user_group() helper as below and solved the issue.

```
if ( !function_exists('get_user_group') )
{
    function get_user_group($uid = FALSE)
    {
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // getting user groups by id or logged in
    $object = $CI->ion_auth->get_users_groups($uid)->result();

    foreach($object as $group):
        $id[] = $group->id;
        $groups[] = $group->name;
    endforeach;
    $groups = array_combine($id, $groups);

    return $groups;

    }
}
```

Hope this may helps to others